# Camera device could not be opened because there are too many other open camera devices

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera, webrtc

I am oppening a cameraCapture ussing

```
      videoCapturer = createVideoCapturer(GlobalStaticData.context);
        videoCapturer.initialize(null,GlobalStaticData.context,null);
        localMediaStream.addTrack(createCapturerVideoTrack(videoCapturer));
        // Create audio track
        videoCapturer.startCapture(640, 480, 15);

        if (videoCapturer == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error while opening camera");
            return;
        }

    }
    localMediaStream.addTrack(createCapturerAudioTrack(factory.createAudioTrack(AUDIO_TRACK_ID, factory.createAudioSource(audioConstraints))));
```

and closing it via

```
   videoSource.dispose();
   videoCapturer.stopCapture();
   videoCapturer.dispose();
```

But when I try to reopen again the camera, it throws me an error saying

> E/org.webrtc.Logging: Camera2Session: Error: Camera device could not
>   be opened because there are too many other open camera devices and i
>   checked ussing CameraManager and it seems that the camera is
>   unavailable.

I am ussing:
**'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.23546'** latest version at this time. Am I doing something wrong . I couldn't find any documentation about this.
   Is there a way to release the unavailable camera resources ?

Comment: you find any solution ?

Comment: any solution to this?